# How to log the whole SMTP session including DATA with postfix?

Tags: debian, postfix

I am running a Debian 8.5 with postifx 2.11.3-1 and i try to log the whole smtp session including DATA to `mail.log`.

it was possible to see a part of the data by increasing the verbosity by adding `-vvv` to the `smtpd` in the `master.cf` (see whole file below) but it wasn't possible for me to get the complete data, only the first 10 chars are being logged.

mail.log

```
--- snip ---
Sep 18 18:22:03 vagrant postfix/smtpd[9220]: rec_put: type T len 17 data 1474215723
Sep 18 18:22:03 vagrant postfix/smtpd[9220]: rec_put: type A len 18 data log_ident=
Sep 18 18:22:03 vagrant postfix/smtpd[9220]: rec_put: type A len 21 data rewrite_co
Sep 18 18:22:03 vagrant postfix/smtpd[9220]: rec_put: type S len 23 data foo@exampl
Sep 18 18:22:03 vagrant postfix/smtpd[9220]: rec_put: type A len 25 data log_client
--- snip ---
```

also by increasing the verbosity postfix really logs a lot. is there a better way rather then increasing verbosity level?

as far as i found out it is only possible to use tcpdump or whireshark to really only log the smtp session, do i see this correct?

example smtp session of what i want to log:

```
telnet www.sample.com 25

Server Response: 220 www.sample.com ESMTP Postfix
Client Sending : HELO domain.com
Server Response: 250 Hello domain.com
Client Sending : MAIL FROM: <me@domain.com>
Server Response: 250 Ok
Client Sending : RCPT TO: <friend@sample.com>
Server Response: 250 Ok
Client Sending : DATA
Server Response: 354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
Client Sending : Subject: Example Message
Client Sending : From: me@domain.com
Client Sending : To: you@sample.com
Client Sending :
Client Sending : Yo,
Client Sending :
Client Sending :   Sending a test message.
Client Sending :
Client Sending :   Later,
Client Sending : Carl
Client Sending : .
Server Response: 250 Ok: queued as 45334
Client Sending : QUIT
Server Response: 221 Bye
```

master.cf

```
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd -vvv

pickup    unix  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr

tlsmgr    unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp

showq     unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)

ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -   n   n   -   2   pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}
```

main.cf

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = localhost.at.dev
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = localhost.at.dev
mydestination = localhost.at.dev, localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
```

Comment: http://serverfault.com/a/419829/126632

Answer (score -1):

It is really hard to log at that level and have a usable log. I've only seen it in clients set to debug level.  You might be able to do a log per message that is useful.

Is there any reason you need a log at this level?  You should be able to create a shadow copy of the message, but that would exclude the commands used.

It is relatively easy to get the commands in `exim4`, but I don't think it as easy to get the responses.  Data is another matter, but you should be able to capture the spool file that contains the data.  I believe it is more difficult to get the commands in Postfix due to the way it is structured.

Answer (score -2):

One way would be to record the TCP session using a tool like wireshark or tcpdump.

Comment: If you take into account everything is encrypted nowadays this would be useless suggestion at best. Michael Hampton posted a comment with the link to the correct way to do that in Postfix. There you'll also find an explanation why *your* suggestion is not just useless, it is bad.